# Tables not showing in database

Tags: sql-server

I create a database named Anandschool and tables inside named teacher inside database.
when i see in right hand side in database then it shows only system table but when i apply command ""**select * from teacher**"" then it showing.
How can i see tables name in right side of database.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The query window is in the context of the `master` database.

[image]

You need to execute `USE AnandSchool;` at the top of the query window.  Subsequent attempts to `SELECT * FROM ...` will return an error message.

Prior to creating a table using T-SQL, you need to ensure the query window is using the correct database.

Comment: Nice point noted max. Sharp eyesight +1

Comment: Eugh. Yeah, sorry. Somehow I thought he'd created that previously on the database...